# JAXB unmarshall issue

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I've to parse the following xml in a Java object:

```
<ArrayOfTranslateArrayResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<TranslateArrayResponse>
    <From>it</From>
    <OriginalTextSentenceLengths xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:int>5</a:int>
    </OriginalTextSentenceLengths>
    <TranslatedText>Mom</TranslatedText>
    <TranslatedTextSentenceLengths xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:int>3</a:int>
    </TranslatedTextSentenceLengths>
</TranslateArrayResponse>
<TranslateArrayResponse>
    <From>it</From>
    <OriginalTextSentenceLengths xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:int>4</a:int>
    </OriginalTextSentenceLengths>
    <TranslatedText>Dad</TranslatedText>
    <TranslatedTextSentenceLengths xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:int>3</a:int>
    </TranslatedTextSentenceLengths>
</TranslateArrayResponse>
```

This the two class I've implemented:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="ArrayOfTranslateArrayResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class TranslateResponse {

    @XmlElement(name="TranslateArrayResponse")
    private LinkedList<TranslatedResponseObject> translations;

}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class TranslatedResponseObject {

    @XmlElement(name="TranslatedText")
    private String translatedText;


}
```

With the unmarshall of the xml example provided, I received null for the field translations. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solutions, thanks to @klonq suggestion to debug the issue. It was necessary to add the namespace on each @XmlElement and @XmlRootElement, in this way:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ArrayOfTranslateArrayResponse", namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class TranslateResponse {

    @XmlElement(name="TranslateArrayResponse", namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2")
    private LinkedList<TranslatedResponseObject> translations;

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class TranslatedResponseObject {

    @XmlElement(name="TranslatedText", namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2")
    private String translatedText;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ValidationEventHandler to debug problems.

```
public class MyValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {

        switch (event.getSeverity()) {

            case ValidationEvent.WARNING: 
            case ValidationEvent.ERROR: 
            case ValidationEvent.FATAL_ERROR: {
                log.error("Validation event : {} in {} line {} col {}",
                          event.getMessage(),
                          event.getLocator().getURL(),
                          event.getLocator().getLineNumber(),
                          event.getLocator().getColumnNumber());
                return false;
            }
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And you use it like the following :

```
final JAXBContext jAXBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(target);
final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jAXBContext.createUnmarshaller();

unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());

unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion! Here the error: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2", local:"ArrayOfTranslateArrayResponse"). Expected elements are <{}ArrayOfTranslateArrayResponse>,<{}TranslateArrayRequest>